# One NSDictionary visible everywhere in application

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsdictionary, global

Now I am developing an iOS application which works like this:
User scans QR code,
App searches for a specific key - > value,
it gives out a value to the user.

Currently I have two ViewControllers - the main and "value" ViewController, which is inherited from main. The problem is that if I create NSDictionary in main VC it is not visible in "value" VC. Main VC gives only the string (QR code, the key) through the segue. So, the value VC has to search for key and display the value.

What I ask is some kind of global variable or one DataSource visible across the whole app. Of course, I can implement NSDictionary initialisation inside value ViewDidLoad method and it will work, but this is not the point. New modules are to be added there and the variable has to be global. I googled a lot and got the idea that singleton pattern can be helpful here. I tried to implement it, but no idea how to do. Do I need it, or it is too complex for this kind of DataSource?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is, you will still need to #include the header file of the place where this dictionary will be. The solution that Naveen proposes means that you will be including the header for the app delegate wherever you want to access it. Whether to use the app delegate for this purpose or not is kinda grayish. Some people often do this, some say its a bad use of it.

The singleton approach means that you will create a class, that will always contain the same information since the init method will return object that was previously created.

For the singleton aproach, imagine I have a database manager class. So in the header of this class (the DatabaseManagerSingleton.h) ill have this:

```
@interface DatabaseManager : NSObject

+ (DatabaseManager*)sharedInstance;

// Your dictionary
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary* someDictionary;
```

The implementation will look like this: (check how "sharedInstance" initializes the object)

```
@implementation DatabaseManager

#pragma mark - Singleton Methods

+ (DatabaseManager*)sharedInstance {

    static DatabaseManager *_sharedInstance;
    if(!_sharedInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
        dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
            _sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
        });
    }

    return _sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

    return [self sharedInstance];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // Custom initialization
        _someDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, a VERY important thing is that, any place you want to use this object should first include the header:

**EDIT: To use it in your code:**

1) add the header

```
#import "DatabaseManager.h"
```

2) initialize the object

```
DatabaseManager *databaseManager = [DatabaseManager sharedInstance];
```

3) do whatever you need

```
// Initialize the dictionary
databaseManager.someDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"OBJECT",@"someKey", nil];  // In this case the object is just a NSString.

// Access
[databaseManager.someDictionary objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```

Comment: Thank you! This is actually a point with which I came up and hit the wall. How can I add objects to the NSDictionary with method e.g. initWithObjectsAndKeys? How can I access that dictionary with method objectForKey?

Comment: check the edit (also i changed the dictionary to mutable one for ur purpose)

Comment: Note that that's easily twice as much code as if you use the app delegate.

Comment: @HotLicks yes it is, thats a drawback

Comment: @RichardTopchiy Check the second edit. After you intialize it, databaseManager contains is as a property accessible by databaseManager.someDictionary.

Comment: Much better solution than using the App Delegate. [Don't abuse the App Delegate](http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/).

Comment: Decided to use this solution instead of AppDelegate variant. Mainly, because this was the solution I searched for and tried to implement. Thanks to everybody (and of course, for Chiquis) for answers and discussion. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Put as a property on Appdelegate

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary * sharedData;
```

Access anywhere like

```
NSDictionary *sharedData= ((APPDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sharedData;
```

Comment: The first part is OK and understandable but the second is the reason for error. Could you explain the code in the second string you've mentioned, please?

Comment: Write a macro or a class method on APPDelegate to make the access simpler.

Comment: A singleton in a specific class is better than an AppDelegate property.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy -- The APPDelegate (if you choose to name it that) class is a subclass of UIApplicationDelegate, and specified when you start the app.  `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` returns a pointer to the APPDelegate class and the rest is to cast it to the proper type and access the property.

Comment: /*My fault. Its OK, I had to import "AppDelegate.h". But still, please, explain the code, especially pointer to AppDelegate. Thank you!*/ Im too slow

Comment: @CrimsonChris - Why?  The app delegate is already there, and is intended for this sort of thing.  Besides which, if that's your opinion you should write your own answer.

Comment: @HotLicks I also don't think is meant to be used like this, i remember asking the same a very long time and was told the same. After all it is the file that works as the delegate of the application. A singleton might be a more elegant solution since adding code to work with the dictionary wont make the app delegate get cluttered by unrelated methods after.

Comment: @HotLicks, can you support "is intended for this sort of thing"?  Isn't the intent to develop an NSObject subclass as the root of your model, often (but not always) a singleton?  AppDelegate seems to me to be the go to place if you just don't want to think too hard about the model.

Comment: @Chiquis - A singleton is certainly more complex approach, if that's what you're after.  And it's "in" these days.  But the app delegate has always been used in this fashion.

Comment: The app delegate has been around since before "singleton" was even a word (or at least a word used in this sense).

Comment: Using a separate class keeps the code cleaner. Think "Single Responsibility Principle".  Also, read this http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/.

Comment: @HotLicks The singleton pattern is pretty darn old. It is surely older than iOS.

Comment: @CrimsonChris - Certainly statics have been around since the dawn of computing, and a singleton is at heart a fancy static.  But if you go back to about 3 hours after dawn you will see that statics were roundly (and justly) criticized for encouraging poor coding practices.  The "singleton" has been promoted primarily as a way to disguise the use of statics and make a poor programming practice more acceptable.

Comment: I'm not promoting the use of the singleton pattern. I'm saying that if you must use a singleton, don't put it in the App Delegate.